# Verifying a cycle of values in table

Tags: sql

I have a table which looks like this (the real table has dates and time in place of the Letters):

```
| assigned   | start       | end 
| xyz        |      A      |     B     
| xyz        |      B      |     C     
| xyz        |      C      |     D     
| xyz        |      D      |     E     
| xyz        |      E      |     F    
| fgh        |      A      |     B
| fgh        |      B      |     C
```

etc.

There is a rotation with each assigned code (xyz,fgh and so on) where 'end' is congruent with the next 'start' up to a value indicating a defined end (here 'F').

I am looking for a statement which scans/verifys that this rotation is indeed occurring, that it starts at A and ends with F and did every step up until then.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: The rotation always uses 5 rows (or 4 steps), even if the intervall length can change in between.

Comment: Do the dates in start and end fields have any uniform intervals to the next record? Like can we say that this transform happens once in a day?

Comment: Sadly no. The only connection is always that the start date and end date are the same, e.g. start date 04/26/2013 and end date 06/01/2013, the dates in between (from start to end of the rotation) can differ for assigned codes (xyz, fgh, etc.).

Comment: On the other hand, the transformation does happen in a uniform time frame if that helps, only the intervals in between can differ.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: at the moment MySQL actually..

Answer (score 0):

This is really a hack that works because the dates are replaced by characters, but it might give you ideas on how to make it work for real.

```
select * from (
  select a_code, min(a_start) as thestart, max(a_end) as theend,
       substring(group_concat(a_start order by a_start), 3) as starts, 
       substring(group_concat(a_end order by a_end), 1, length(group_concat(a_end))-2) as  ends
  from so_test
  group by a_code ) as grpSelect
where thestart = 'a'
and theend = 'f'
and starts = ends
```

The group_concat of a_start for xyz prduces a string of 'a,b,c,d,e' while the group_concat for a_end prduces b,c,d,e,f.  The substring removes the a from the start and the f from the end so that the outer query can compare b,c,d,e in both strings.

Comment: Thanks! I'm testing that at the moment and see what you did there. Now I wish there weren't any dates,haha. I try to fiddle with that a bit.